# Erro ao rodar programa

Tags: c, for

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<math.h>

int main ( void ){
int x;
int i;
printf("Input the number (Table to be calculated) : ");
scanf("%d", x);

for( i = 1; i <= 10; i++){

    printf("%d x %d = %d", x, i, x*i);
}
return 0;

}
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Gostaria de saber o motivo do erro? 
já tentei criando uma variavel pra segurar o valor de x*i dentro do loop, mas ainda assim não funciona, depois que dou o primeiro input visto na tela, o Windows identifica um problema...

Comment: Falta o `&` no `scanf()`. Precisa informar qual endereço de memória receberá o valor inteiro. Neste caso, o endereço da variável `x`. Então passe `&x`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Após o primeiro parâmetro, a função [`scanf`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/scanf/) espera receber uma [referência](http://www.cprogressivo.net/2013/03/Variaveis-apontadas-A-passagem-por-Referencia-em-C.html) à variável que pretende guardar o valor da entrada:

```
scanf("%d", &x);
```

Espero ter ajudado.

Answer (score -2):

além do "&" em "scanf" como já foi mencionado, você colocou na função main o void e no final do código "return 0", e isso está errado pois void não retorna nada.

Comment: `int main` significa que o retorno é `int`, e não `void`.